# Mat to Byte[] conversion not working in java

Tags: java, opencv

I tried to convert Mat to byte array in java . On conversion of Mat to Byte[] and Byte[] to Mat, I am not able to retain the original value of Mat. The Mat .get accepts byte[] as parameter which is not working. Can anyone help me with the same?

Use Case: To grab each frame of video and send it via kafka to consumer containing byte[] message then consumer would recieve the byte array and convert to Mat and save it as image.

I came accross similar posts in java but no solution was found. [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/51335/getting-a-blank-image/)

See my code:

```
`       System.loadLibrary("opencv_java249");
        MatOfByte webcam_image = new MatOfByte();
        VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(
                "/home/jishnu/CodeT/TrainingDataSet/Video.mp4");
        System.out.println("Frame Grabber started");
        byte[] frameArray;
        int i=0;
        if (capture.isOpened()) {
            while (true) {
                capture.read(webcam_image);
                frameArray = new byte[(int) (webcam_image.total() * webcam_image
                    .channels())];
            if (!webcam_image.empty()) {                    
            //  System.out.print(".");  
                webcam_image.get(0,0,frameArray);

                producer.send(new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>("imageTopic",frameArray));

                //Below statements are only for debugging
                System.out.println(frameArray.length);      
                MatOfByte inputframe=new MatOfByte(frameArray);
                boolean b=  Highgui.imwrite("/home/jishnu/CodeT/Today7.jpeg", inputframe);

                if(b){System.out.println("save image success");}
                else System.out.println("save image failed");

                inputframe.fromArray(frameArray);
                b=  Highgui.imwrite("/home/jishnu/CodeT/Today6.bmp",inputframe);

                if(b){System.out.println("save image success");System.exit(0);}
                else System.out.println("save image failed");

            } else {
                System.out.println(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
```

`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's working me.I use [apachi-common](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/commons-io/commons-io-2.4.jar.zip) for write and read from file.

```
public static void save(Mat mat, String name)
        {
            File file = new File(path, name);
            int length = (int) (mat.total() * mat.elemSize());
            byte buffer[] = new byte[length];
            mat.get(0, 0, buffer);
            try
                {
                    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, buffer);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

 public static Mat load(String name)
        {
            File file = new File(path, name);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
            try
                {
                    buffer = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            Mat mat = new Mat(row, col, type);
            mat.put(0, 0, buffer);
            return mat;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV version : 4.5.1

Refarance: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-opencv-mat-object-to-bufferedimage-object-using-java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = ".jpg";
    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
    Mat mat=Imgcodecs.imread(filePath); 

    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", mat, matOfByte);
    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
    
    Path path = Paths.get("D:\\yyy2.jpg");
    Files.write(path, byteArray);
    //InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets the same error.
I used `Mat.put(frameArray)` to create Mat from byte instead of  `MatOfByte inputframe=new MatOfByte(frameArray);`
Now everything is working fine, I dont know why is MatofByte constructor not working.

**Fixed in later versions of JavaCV.**